# Jquery click event not working on li in devices(ipad, iphone..)

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

Jquery click event is not working on li in devices. I tried using click and touchstart events, but the problem when touchstart used is I couldn't scroll down the div. When I try to scroll down by clicking an li, it gets selected. Is there any way to select and scroll li using any jquery events rather than jquery mobile events?

```
$('#liId').on({ 'touchstart' : function(){ console.log('Event Fired'} });
```

Comment: Try `$('#liId').on( 'touchstart', function(){ console.log('Event Fired'); });`

Comment: The event got fired, but the thing is I couldn't scroll down.

Comment: Try this example http://jsfiddle.net/coma/9KvhL/25/

Answer (score 9):

The issue is solved when I added a style class to all li.

.liClass { cursor : pointer; }

Answer (score 1):

replace `:` with `,` and unwrap `{}` before 'touchstart'

```
$('#liId').on( 'touchstart', function(){ 
 console.log('Event Fired');
});
```

Comment: Well I tried that too...I'm getting the event, but I couldn't scroll the div.When the event is fired the li which fired the touchstart event gets selected.

Comment: @ABHILASHSB check the css of that items.  I doubt the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

in your css file

```
#liId { cursor : pointer; }
```

jQuery

```
$('#liId').click(function(){
    alert('Event Fired');
});
```