# Click events not firing on iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios

I have a list with nested lists that I want to open upon clicking them. It works fine on desktop, and across various browser, but when I use iOS, either iPad or iPhone, it does not want to work.

the list looks like so:

```
<ul class="lessonList">
   <li class="lessonItem" id="1"><input type="checkbox" class="scopeCheck">Default Scope
      <ul style="display:none;" class="scope1">...other content in here</ul>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

and the code like so :

```
$(document).on("click",".lessonItem",function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();

});
```

I have a stop immediateprop to stop clicking the checkbox from activating the slidetoggle however on iOS, it will not even drop until (and only if) you check off the checkbox. clicking on the li itself does nothing in the iOS devices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add this style to the `<li>` element, it works:

```
li { cursor: pointer; }
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/ohhyz8hz/)

It seems to be a bug with iOS events – [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396207/jquery-click-event-not-working-on-li-in-devicesipad-iphone).

Comment: Wow, what an odd fix. Any idea why it works this way?

Comment: @ajmajmajma iOS has an odd problem where click events only delegate to parent elements when the element clicked is actually a link. This can be an `a` element for instance. However, for some reason iOS also counts elements that have `cursor: pointer;` applied. Another fix is adding `onclick="none()"` to your element. For more information, see: https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this issue as well and the CSS cursor trick didn't work for me.

Luckily after some playing around I found that the click event is always transmitted to anchor tags, and was able fix my issue by changing my Div containers to Anchor tags.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I also found that binding to 'touchstart' as well as 'click' worked for me.

Comment: Hello! the cursor trick also not working for me. Can you please check my codes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309543/how-to-fix-event-listener-on-ios

Answer (score 2):

This occurs under very specific conditions:

- have a :hover rule for an element that is clickable. The styles in that rule don't matter, the rule can even be empty.
- have a CSS3 adjacent sibling rule with a most specific term that matches at least one element in the DOM. It doesn't need to match the entire rule. Again, the rule can even be empty.
- The clickable element is followed by an  element (which could also be wrapped as the first element inside a  element).

You have a :hover rule for an element that is clickable. The styles in that rule don't matter, the rule can even be empty.
and you have a CSS3 adjacent sibling rule with a most specific term that matches at least one element in the DOM. It doesn't need to match the entire rule. Again, the rule can even be empty.
and the clickable element is followed by an  element (which could also be wrapped as the first element inside a  element).
In that case, tapping the clickable element (whether that click is a JavaScript onclick handler, or just a simple ) does not register. Instead, it applies the :hover style and only on the second tap does it navigate or run the JavaScript. This happens only on Mobile SafariChanging pretty much anything will make the bug disappear, so all of these are valid workarounds:

after checking our code all these conditions apply for us, but will also be impractical to but removing these conditions.

Comment: This is my case but I'm quite confused how should I fix this bug.