# How to fix event listener on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I've a site where videos will be loaded and played on hover/tap on the images. The site is working as expected on all the devices except for the apple(iOS) devices.

When I tap on the image, the video container doesn't shows up. I've found some answers that adding cursor: pointer, or adding onClick event listener fix this. I've tried this (not sure if I did it right) but failed. How to fix this?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".column");

                columns.forEach((column) => {
                    const thumbnail = column.querySelector(".thumbnail");
                    const videoContainer =
                        column.querySelector(".video-container");
                    const video = videoContainer.querySelector("video");
                    let isVideoLoaded = false;

                    video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
                        thumbnail.style.opacity = "0";
                        video.style.display = "block";
                        isVideoLoaded = true;
                    });

                    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);

                    if (window.matchMedia("(hover: hover)").matches) {
                        // Device supports hover (desktop/laptop)
                        column.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter);
                        column.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
                        column.addEventListener("click", handleClickInside);
                    } else if (window.matchMedia("(hover: none)").matches) {
                        // Device does not support hover (mobile)
                        column.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
                            handleTouchStart();
                            handleClickInside();
                        });
                        column.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
                    }

                    async function handleTouchEnd(event) {
                        if (!player.paused()) {
                            return;
                        }

                        await loadVideoIfNotLoaded();
                        hideThumbnailAndPlay();
                    }

                    async function loadVideoIfNotLoaded() {
                        if (!isVideoLoaded) {
                            await loadVideo();
                        }
                    }

                    async function loadVideo() {
                        const dataSrc = video.getAttribute("data-src");
                        if (dataSrc && !isVideoLoaded) {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                video.src = dataSrc;
                                video.load();
                                video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
                                    isVideoLoaded = true;
                                    resolve();
                                });
                                video.addEventListener("error", reject);
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    function hideThumbnailAndPlay() {
                        thumbnail.style.opacity = "0";
                        videoContainer.style.display = "block";
                        player.play();
                    }

                    function handleMouseEnter() {
                        if (!player.paused()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        loadVideoIfNotLoaded()
                            .then(hideThumbnailAndPlay)
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error("Error loading video:", error);
                            });
                    }

                    function handleMouseLeave() {
                        thumbnail.style.opacity = "1";
                        player.pause();
                        player.currentTime(0);
                        videoContainer.style.display = "none";
                    }

                    function handleTouchStart(event) {
                        loadVideoIfNotLoaded()
                            .then(hideThumbnailAndPlay)
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error("Error loading video:", error);
                            });
                    }

                    function handleClickOutside(event) {
                        const isClickInsideVideoContainer =
                            event.target.closest(".video-container");
                        const videoContainers =
                            document.querySelectorAll(".video-container");

                        if (!isClickInsideVideoContainer) {
                            videoContainers.forEach((container) => {
                                const video = container.querySelector("video");
                                const thumbnail =
                                    container.parentElement.querySelector(
                                        ".thumbnail"
                                    );

                                thumbnail.style.opacity = "1";
                                player.pause();
                                player.currentTime(0);
                                container.style.display = "none";
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    function handleClickInside() {
                        if (!video.paused) {
                            handleClick();
                        }
                    }

                    function handleClick() {
                        alert("Hi!");
                    }

                    // Initialize the video player
                    const player = videojs(video, {
                        autoplay: false,
                        muted: true,
                        loop: true,
                    });
                });
            });
```

```css
.container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: auto auto;
                gap: 5rem;
            }

            .column {
                position: relative;
            }

            .thumbnail {
                height: 100%;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .thumbnail img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            .video-container {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .video-container video {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            @media (max-width: 650px) {
                .container {
                    grid-template-columns: auto;
                }
            }
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1684482570533-b97679dd0705?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4fHx8ZW58MHx8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                        alt=""
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video
                        data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/431680358.sd.mp4?s=3f97b05e5d5dab21298a96bb5653849567aaf675&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                        type="video/mp4"
                    ></video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685796766-0fddd3e480de?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzNnx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                        alt=""
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video
                        data-src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/503759306.sd.mp4?s=273116dd8b495498766d3fe03e8416fff0cc68b5&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761"
                        type="video/mp4"
                    ></video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: I’m not understanding something - why are you using data-src rather than src in the video element’s attributes?

Comment: @AHaworth So, that the video doesn't get preloaded.

Comment: Thanks, understood. It seems as though the src attribute isn't actually getting updated - although JS claims it has (ie when I look with the browser's devtools inspect facility with say an iPhone emulation it is not there after a click, but on the desktop after a click it is).